# Very slow TLS handshake on certain sites across different browsers

Tags: 16.04, networking, browser, tls

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have been experiencing a very particular issue with a certain set of webpages.

The first visit of some pages (see list below) within a certain timeframe (~5min) is very slow. In particular, the TLS Handshake takes 30+ seconds. Once the connection has been established, follow up visits to the page are fine for a few minutes until the problem resets.

This issue occurs across all browsers (Firefox default, Brave, Chrome).

I have tried to reset my networking settings as the problem does not seem to be specific to the browser. In the case of Chrome most pages even time out (e.g., `github.com took too long to respond.`)

Problematic pages & services:

- github.com (requests via CLI work perfectly fine)
- twitter.com
- rescuetime.com (the firefox extension fails to connect with the service)

I am honestly quite lost regarding this issue. Hoping that someone has an idea/hint for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you discover anything? I've just migrated to Ubuntu 22.10 from Windows 11. Everything the same but new OS. Noticed rather quickly that web pages act laggy. Network (in DevTools) requests' timelines tab shows that TLS handshakes take insane durations. I'm running Ethernet.